# Request : I am able to apply masger page (v4.master) for child sites and parent sites. But not able to view changes for users other than Admin

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In sharepoint 2010, with Admin login can view master page changes in parent and child sites(i.e. all) but others users (who are readers, contributers,etc)login can view changes in Child sites but not parent sites.
Please help me. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be couple of reasons for the behavior: 
1) Security inheritance is broken between your parent and child sites (not necessarily a bad thing but a reason for different expectations) And

2) Make sure your master page changes are checked in and published.. in other words latest version of master page should be a major version like 1.0, 2.0 etc

Comment: Thanks for information, I was updated the master page same time with all the parent and child sites and immedieatly checked-in. Let me double check version info. I am not sure about security inheritacne is broken. Please advise me.